# How to pass data to a not running App with custom url scheme?

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme

There are two Apps called Sender and Receiver, I implement the custom url scheme to pass data

Now, I can pass data by using the url scheme

Sender code :

```
@IBAction func SendButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let sendTextMessage : String = sendText.text!
    let ourApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    let ourPath : String = "iOSTest://?\(sendTextMessage)"
    let ourUrl : NSURL = NSURL(string: ourPath)!
    if ourApplication.canOpenURL(ourUrl) {
        ourApplication.openURL(ourUrl)
    } else {
        print("The App doesn't install")
    }
}
```

Receiver code in App-delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    return true
}


func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    calledBy = sourceApplication
    fullUrl = url.absoluteString
    scheme = url.scheme
    query = url.query

    return true
}
```

Receiver code in ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.displayLaunchDetails), name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}
```

I read the document from Apple
[UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/)

It seems that when my app is in foreground, the data pass will work.

When the receiver is not running, I also can open the Receiver by openURL. But the data I pass didn't show.

Really need some informations!

Comment: Do you return `true` or `false` from the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method? If you return `false`, the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method won't be called.

Comment: Actually, I return true in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions! I think didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is just to decide whether to open the url or not ?